# Find the quotes

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle

> Lang's teacher gave a piece of paper to Lang and said to him, "*Three good quotes are written here. But you have to achieve them through some difficulties*". The following was written in the paper:
> (a) CAJEQO EO KJA LANYAJP EJOLENWPEKJ WJZ JEJAPU-JEJA LANYAJP LANOLENWPEKJ.
> (b) ZIQQHUV QHYHU TXLW DQG TXLWWHUV QHYHU ZLQ.
> (c) NRFLNSFYNTS NX RTWJ NRUTWYFSY YMFS PSTBQJILJ.
> **Can you find the quotes?**

**Note:** The problem is taken from the book *Neurone Onuronon* by *Muhammad Zafar Iqbal*. I don't have any solution to the problem. Thinking mathematically might help as the book is on *mathematical puzzles*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is basically a

> shift cipher, where the value to shift is different for each line. 
>  Using ROT4 on (a), you get "GENIUS IS ONE PERCENT INSPIRATION AND NINETY-NINE PERCENT PERSPIRATION."
>  Using ROT23 on (b), you get "WFNNERS NEVER QUIT AND QUITTERS NEVER WIN." (probably an error as I think it should be WINNERS.)
>  Using ROT21 on (c), you get "IMAGINATION IS MORE IMPORTANT THAN KNOWLEDGE."